# Clone and append to closes td element within a cell

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of table cells. in a particular cell I want to clone and append a dropdown list. How do I do this? Here's what I've tried but it doesn't work. I'm trying to clone a dropdown and change multiple attributes and then add it to the existing cell that the script is found in.

```
<td>
<script>
var newDD = $('#aud1-clone').clone().attr({'id':'aud1','data-acID':'9857','data-pos':'1','name':'aud1'});
$(this).closest('td').appendTo(newDD);
</script>    
</td>

<select id="aud1-clone">
    <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just a quick look makes me confused as to what you are doing. you are using appendTo on the new element you are creating?

Comment: What is: `$(this)`? Whatever it is it has to be ***inside the `<td>`***

Comment: sorry... i was trying to say $(this) as in where the script is located... find the closest td to that and append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using appendTo correctly.
You are telling it to append to the element you just created which isn't even part of the DOM yet.
Your script may work if you change "appendTo" to just "append"

--edit--
I don't think you understand "appendTo".  http://api.jquery.com/appendto/
It works different than ".append()".  you should have the target element in the appendTo().  Example from Jquery:

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );
```

Where ".inner" is the target element you want to append to.  In your case, you are creating an object "newDD",  then you are selecting a "td" and attempting to append it to your new object.  But you also never append your new object to the DOM.
Also, you can't use $(this) like that. It should refer to a dom element, such as a button that is clicked to trigger a script.  you can't just refer to your script location.
you should probably do something like $("#aud1-clone").closest('td')...
But you should make sure to run that script after the page is rendered, maybe using $(document).ready().

Comment: i was trying to say $(this) as in where the script is located... find the closest td to that and append